# WP8 MPNS custom sound file not played completely

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have implemented custom sound for push notifications in wp8. Everything works fine , but the custom sound file is not played completely (when app is in background). the sound file is 8 seconds and meets requirements. can someone let me know why the sound file is not played completely ?